# How does nodejs server, for nodemailer, works when hosted?

Tags: node.js, angular, email, ionic-framework, nodemailer

I am a beginner with Ionic, Angular, CSS, HTML etc, and I am a bit confused about nodejs server. I want to make a PWA (using Ionic 5 and Angular 8) and host it on Firebase, with a Spark plan.

One of the features of this platform is sending an e-mail, containing the user's doubts, to the administrator. After some research, I planned to use nodemailer, as I can't send a message directly with Angular (front end framework).

Finally, my question is: if I host my entire platform on Firebase, how does this nodejs server work? I need to host it in another firebase project?

My sources are: [mailtrap.io](https://blog.mailtrap.io/angular-send-email/#Backend_is_required_to_send_emails_with_Angular), [FunOfHeuristic's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p4bnK0qy89w)